# HOw to put condition statement for the following ASp.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in the front end

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //on upload button click temporarily disables ajax to perform upload actions
            function conditionalPostback(sender, args) 
            {
                if (args.EventTarget == '<%= ((Button)frmvwMainDetail.FindControl("bttnRateUploadUpload")).UniqueID %>') {
                    args.EnableAjax = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    ...
</asp:content>
```

When the page load, it' complaining about ((Button)frmvwMainDetail.FindControl("bttnRateUploadUpload")).UniqueID is null value. So my question how to put some checking on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ClientID not UniqueID

- The control's UniqueID property is   rendered as the name attribute.
- The control's ClientID property is   rendered as the id attribute.

Do something with your code `OnPageLoad`:

```
// Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
      String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World:"+ bttnRateUploadUpload.ClientID + "');";
      cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1);
    }
```

Comment: Actually ... that bttnRateUploadUpload is not exist yet. BTW ... I am using the FormView and ths thing happen on Insert view mode which is explain that bttnRateUploadUpload button is not exist yet. So that why I am just how to check to not running at all the JS if the object is null.

Comment: see my edited answer. you may check something rules and decide to add or don't add script to page at that point. so use your control.ClientID to insert reference to it in the client script.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I will try this approach

Comment: I've try your approach by putting that modified code above into CONDITIONAL that I want BUT it keeps saying when I debugged: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'conditionalPostback' is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I changed from RegisterStartupScript to RegisterBlockScript and no complain.